# Quando combinar a preposição «de» com os artigos indefinidos?

Tags: gramática, preposições

As combinações *dum*, *duns*, *duma* e *dumas* normalmente são facultativas.

Em quais contextos poderia ser obrigatória ou impossível essa combinação?  E nos casos opcionais (que acho a maioria), há padrões que influam a seleção do falante?  Imagino, por exemplo, que quando *um* ou *uma* é usado como número seria abnormal a combinação.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nunca é obrigatório contrair *de* com *um* e há casos em que essa hipótese está afastada.

Em primeiro lugar, *de* contrai-se geralmente com o **artigo indefinido** *um* (e *uma*, *uns*, *umas*). Embora não tenha encontrado referências, diria que a análise é a mesma quando *um* é um pronome, e também tenho dúvidas que *um* ser numeral cardinal (admitindo que *um* artigo indefinido e *um* numeral cardinal são de facto entidades distintas) altere a análise (mas se o fizer será de facto no sentido de desfavorecer a contração). Em

> Porque é que me deste dois? Só preciso dum/de um pano.

Diria que *dum* é ainda a forma mais comum na oralidade.

A contração está vedada, pelo menos na norma-padrão (GP, vol. II, p. 1508), nos casos seguintes:

> Quando um pronome pessoal ou um determinante inicia uma oração não finita que exclui a preposição, a contração é estigmatizada com *de* e não ocorre com *por*, *com* e *quem* [nota de rodapé: [...] A contração com a preposição *de*, sendo estigmatizada na norma-padrão, é, no entanto, bastante comum na oralidade e mesmo na escrita menos formal].

Assim (exemplos do CETEMPúblico):

> *par=ext218446-pol-92b-1*: A sua derrota marca seguramente o ocaso duma fulgurante, inesperada carreira política. [mas *de uma* também seria possível]
>   *par=ext642558-soc-98b-1*: Quanto à primeira hipótese, o Sindep considera-a «caricata» porque «em vez de um escalão ter três anos, teria dois anos e oito meses». [*??dum escalão* é geralmente considerado incorreto]

A razão por que a segunda frase não admite contração deve-se a o complemento ser a oração "um escalão ter três anos" e não o sintagma nominal "um escalão".

Peres e Móia lamentam a não observação desta regra (que, aliás, consideram "talvez uma guerra perdida" (ACLP, p. 219)) e apresentam um exemplo em que fazer ou não a contração altera o sentido da frase (ACLP, p. 220):

> P. Como acha o senhor presidente que vai resolver-se a situação destes presos?
>   R1. Depende do parlamento aplicar ou não a amnistia.
>   R2. Depende de o parlamento aplicar ou não a aministia.

O exemplo usa o artigo definido, mas a análise seria a mesma com *um*. R1 afirma que está nas mão do parlamento (é da competência do parlamento) aplicar a amnistia, R2 que a situação dos presos está dependente da decisão do parlamento.

Com a preposição *de*, existe apesar de tudo uma opção fonética que permite evitar usar a contração, e ao mesmo tempo não pronunciar a vogal central [ɨ], que tem forte tendência a ser elidida: pronunciar [djũ] em lugar de [dɨũ], transformando [ɨ] em [j].

Por fim, embora não tenha encontrado referências neste sentido, é importante sublinhar que a contração nunca é obrigatória na escrita; pelo contrário, tende a ser evitada. A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (GP, p. 1506) apenas lista as contrações de *de* com *onde*, *outro* e *algum* como facultativas, mas é fácil verificar que, na escrita, "de um" é muito mais comum do que "dum", apesar de os casos em que "dum" está tendencialmente vedado serem uma minoria.
O CETEMPúblico tem apenas 3284 ocorrências para "dum", mas 294179 (!) para "de um". Na oralidade, contudo, será mais difícil encontrar "de um" fora dos casos em que "dum" está vedado, mas não tenho nada que apoie esta afirmação exceto a minha (limitada) experiência.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu vi tanto as formas *de um* ou *dum* são corretas.
Entretanto pelo menos que sei aqui no Brasil, *dum* é sentido mais como coloquial.